# Why PWA angular 8 app getting 403 webmanifest GET error

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, angular8, angular-service-worker

First of all when I am loading my application it is not coming at first . I have to reload my page. Then I can see my login page. Upon login also when I am hitting 3-4 times it is redirecting to my dashboard.

I can see on console there is manifest 403 error
`GET https://xyz-devserver.io/manifest.webmanifest 403` .

I believe there is some caching problem happening in my PWA service worker.

Also when I am loading my app , at first I can see install app icon on url bar but I cannon see the loaded login landing page. Upon refreshing the page I can see login UI but now that install app icon disappears.

For multiple click in login I am getting this error:-

`ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.`

What is the problem for this I can't figure this out.

Comment: 403 means you are not authorized. Make sure your manifest file is available without an authentication token. 
Another thought is to make sure you have the right Content-Type header on the manifest, application/manifest.
Some web servers will make you configure the .manifest type to be served. For example IIS will block it by default.

Comment: @ChrisLove How can I configure manifest file without authentication token ? As my entire app is dependent on authentication and authorisation.

Comment: depends on your cloud-side platform I guess. I use all static web pages and protect data access through the API. So the manifest and HTML templates & pages are all fetch able without a token. You will need to configure your server to apply the same protection.